# Horizontal menu with submenu opened after click

Tags: php, jquery, css

I created an horizontal menu with a submenu. On jsfiddle I don't know with the submenu isn't working correctly at 100% instead on local it does. Here is the working link: http://jsfiddle.net/IronFeast/g8MDP/

And here is the code:

```
<ul id="navbar">
<li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Gallery</a>
<ul class="submenu">
   <li><a href="photogallery1.php">Photogallery 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="photogallery2.php">Photogallery 2</a></li>
   <li><a href="photogallery3.php">Photogallery 3</a></li>
</ul>         
</li>
<li><a href="events.php">Events</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Blog</a>
<ul class="submenu">
   <li><a href="personal.php">Personal</a></li>
   <li><a href="dev.php">Dev</a></li>
</ul> 
</li>
<li><a href="#">About</a>
<ul class="submenu">
   <li><a href="page1.php">Page 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="page2.php">Page 2</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
```

CSS:

```
#navbar {
 background-color: #4E78B4;
 position: absolute;
 text-align: center;
 margin: 0;
 padding-bottom: 7px;
 padding-top: 7px;
 float: left;
 left: 10px;
 width: 940px;    
 font-size: 14px;
 z-index: 100;
}

#navbar li {
 list-style: none;
 float: left; 
 color: #E9EBDE;
 padding-left: 24px;
 padding-right: 4px;
 z-index: 100;
}

#navbar li a {
 display: inline;
 padding-top: 7px;
 padding-bottom: 7px;
 padding-right: 8px;        
 padding-left: 8px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 text-decoration: none; 
 font-weight: bold; 
 color: #ffffff;
 z-index: 100;
 text-align: center;
}

#navbar ul li a {
 display: block;
 padding-top: 6px;
 padding-bottom: 3px;
 padding-right: 8px;
 padding-left: 8px;
 text-decoration: none;
 z-index: 100;
}

#navbar li a:hover {
 color: #000000;
 background-color: #ffffff;
 padding-right: 8px;        
 padding-left: 8px;
 z-index: 100;
}

#navbar li ul{
 display: none;  
 background-color: #41B6DC;
 z-index: 100;
}

#navbar li:hover ul, #navbar li.hover ul {
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 left: 0;
 width: 940px;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;            
 z-index: 100;
 margin-top: 7px;
}

#navbar li:hover li, #navbar li.hover li {
 float: left; 
 z-index: 100;
}

#navbar li:hover li a, #navbar li.hover li a {
 color: #000; 
 z-index: 100;
}

#navbar li li a:hover {
 color: #4E78B4; 
 z-index: 100;
}
```

At the moment when I go with the mouse over the "Gallery", the submenu will open, but if I click on "Photogallery 1" I will go to that page but unfortunately the menu will close when I am in that page.

I'd like that "Gallery" will be highlighted, the submenu will stay opened and also the "Photogallery 1" button will be highlighted.

Any help would be awesome. Thank you in advance

Comment: You need to learn Jquery-Ajax.

Comment: Ohh thank you; browsing on Stack, I found a script and added to js: http://jsfiddle.net/IronFeast/g8MDP/6/
But I can't figure out the problem and why it doesn't work.

Comment: I cannot access to your jsFiddle...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add on photogallery1.php, photogallery2.php, etc class attribute with `hover` as value.

```
<ul id="navbar">
    <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
    <li class="<?php echo $_COOKIE["hover"]; ?>"><a href="#">Gallery</a>
    <ul class="submenu">
       <li><a href="photogallery1.php" class="<?php echo $_COOKIE["selected"]; ?>">Photogallery 1</a></li>
       <li><a href="photogallery2.php">Photogallery 2</a></li>
       <li><a href="photogallery3.php">Photogallery 3</a></li>
    </ul>         
    ...
    ...
</ul>
```

also add on your css:

```
.selected {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

It better to use cookie to save menu state.

Comment: Ok, that's what I've done with other menus. But in this case, sorry I haven't told it, the menu is inside an header.php and I call it in all pages with: `<?php include("header.php"); ?>`

Comment: try use cookie to seve menu state.

Answer (score 1):

I found this tutorial http://line25.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu maybe it can help you but i think you will need to ajust the html and css :S

Hope it helps you